# How to show array in DataGridView in VB.NET without using Database?

Tags: vb.net

I want to show Array1 in column1 in Table format. Array2 in Column2. Array3 in Column3. No need Database connection. Just i'll pass 4 arrays in datagridview or any table and it will display the contents of array. array1=column1, array2=column2 and so on....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using a **For Loop** u can do it easily.

```html
For i As Integer = 0 To array1.GetUpperBound(0)
  Dim x As String() = {array1(i), array2(i), array3(i), array4(i)}
  DataGridView1.Rows.Add(x)
Next
```

Thanx.